# SELECT Unique rows from Datagridview using LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, datagridview, distinct

I am trying to SELECT ALL rows\columns from a datagridview where the first column is unique using LINQ.

Datagridview:

```
1     Blue     1111
1     Blue     1111
2     Green    1234
3     Orange   3211
2     Green    1234
4     Red      2222
```

Trying to get this Output:

```
1     Blue     1111
2     Green    1234
3     Orange   3211
4     Red      2222
```

I was able to use the following code which pulls all unique records from the first column but I am not sure how to get the remaining columns:

```
        Dim unique() As String = (From row As DataGridViewRow In dgvMaestro.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)() _
         Where Not row.IsNewRow _
         Select CStr(row.Cells(0).Value)).Distinct.ToArray

        For Each a As String In unique
            Debug.Print(a)
        Next
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Thanks

Comment: You're saying `Select CStr(row.Cells(0).Value))` - That would only give you the value of the first element (hence 1,2,3,4)... You could return the row by typing `Select row`, but you still need a way to output it then....

Comment: I think that's where I am struggling. I am still trying to familiarize myself with linq but any changes I make to call additional columns breaks the query. If I just specify row then it doesn't let me include the distinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need import 2 namespaces for distinct with linq to use AsEnumerable() method in DataTables and Field() method in DataRows

```
Imports System.Data.DataTableExtensions
Imports System.Data.DataRowExtensions
```

Declare new datatable

```
Dim NewTbl As New System.Data.DataTable
```

Add columns in you scenario

```
NewTbl.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
NewTbl.Columns.Add("Color", GetType(String))
NewTbl.Columns.Add("Value", GetType(Integer))
```

Linq use Table 'TblValues' as you datasource

```
Dim results = (From row in TblValues.AsEnumerable() select col1 = row(Of Integer)("ID"), col2 = row(Of String)("Color"), col3 = row(Of Integer)("Value")).Distinct().ToList()
```

Iterate elements in results with for each, the reason is because results is an object  datarow collection and isn't convert auto to table

```
For each r in results
  Dim Row as System.Data.DataRow = NewTbl.NewRow
  Row("ID") = r.col1
  Row("Color") = r.col2
  Row("Value") = r.col3
  NewTbl.Rows.Add(Row)
next
```

Now you have a DataTable 'NewTbl' with distinct values inside

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this is to write a comparer to compare the entire row.

```
Dim noduplicates = dgvMaestro.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).Distinct(New RowComparer())
```

There are some examples of comparers on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)